# hsqldb view data in test.script file

Tags: hsqldb

I have 2 files `/test/test.script` and `/test/test.properties`. `test.script` is around 55 MB .
I need to view tables and data in this file. I tried with Squirrel client URL `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/test` but I do not see any tables in the public schema.

How do I view the tables and data in the `.script` file?
I even tried `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:/test`

Comment: Copy pasting the script content here will be beneficial. At the very last a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

When the script file is  `/test/test.script`, your file URL should be this:

`jdbc:hsqldb:file:/test/test`